# Http Post not working with Windows 7

Tags: android, http-post

I wrote a code that call jsp page from android java file.In windows xp it was working perfect but when i upgrade to Windows 7 it is not working,even not giving any error or exception.it just stops.I need some suggestion what should be the issue.plzz

Answer (score 1):

Try turning the windows firewall off.  If your code starts working, re-enable the firewall and add a rule to allow your connection.